# Creating a temporary File in Androi d11

Tags: android, storage, android-file, android-11

I need to create a temporary image file for my camera to write it over while it is in `WebView`.

Everything worked fine before I started targeting Android 11, SDK 30.

I have tried to find solutions, I enabled storage permissions: `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES`, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` in manifest, and when the app starts it asks for `new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION, uri)` permission as well.

But even with that my temporary `File` is not being created. I have tried to find solutions but cannot seem to come up with one. Which direction should I look to create the temp file?

My code to create a temp file:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timestamp + "_";
    
    File storageDir = activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
}
```

Comment: Your code is ok and you do not need any permission for it. For no Android version.

Comment: Further: createTempFile() would throw an IOException if it could not create the file.